# Laravel Rest API not working on actual server

Tags: php, api, rest, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to create a small application that uses Laravel REST api as backend and Angular for frontend.

I've managed to display json on the browser in localhost but when I uploaded to 1and1.com server, the index page works fine but api ur such as - xyz.com/public/names gives a 404 page not found error.

My Directory structure

```
 empdir
      empdir-backend
         laravel
      empdir-frontend
         js
         css
         index.html
```

Am I missing some thing.

This is my Route.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('names', function () {
    $data = array(
        1 => "John",
        2 => "Mary",
        3 => "Steven"
    );

    return view('rest', $data);
 });

Route::get('names/{id}', 'NameController@showEmpDetail');
Route::resource('names', 'NameController');
```

Controller.php

```
public function index()
{
    return array(
        1 => "John",
        2 => "Mary",
        3 => "Steven"
    );

}
```

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: If you have pointed your server to serve content from public directory no need to include public in your urls. So try `xyz.com/names` instead of `xyz.com/public/names`.

Comment: yes I've changed that..now it automatically opens the public dir..no need to add public. But the xyz.com/names gives a 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: What is on the apache error.log

Answer (score 1):

you need a .htaccess file with this in it: `
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

`

Comment: where should i place this file?

Comment: and probably you need to remove /public from your call

Comment: ther is already a .htaccess file..adding its content to my post..shld I delete whats in it..?

Comment: I made changes to the original .htacces file by removing "RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]" and adding "RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php/$1 [L]". This worked. But I don't understand why

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with .htaccess file that comes with Laravel.

I removed the following line

```
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

and added

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

It worked after this.

Comment: this brings me 500 server error